# Using the interactive widgets with the bokeh-server (bokeh 0.10.0)

Tags: bokeh

I want to replicate this:
https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/examples/app/sliders_applet/sliders_app.py

On my own multiuser bokeh server (bokeh-server -m).
However the comment clearly states that you have to run:

```
bokeh serve app.py
```

This doesn't seem to be shipped with bokeh 0.10.0.
I would like to publish it like I do with my other interactive plots e.g:

```
    Session().login('tmpuser', 'securepassword')
    output_server('sliders')

    # The modified sliders_app.py code

    cursession().publish()
```

There seems to be a lot of inconsistency between the documentation for different versions and the available examples.
The server documentation here is easy to follow: http://docs.bokeh.org/en/0.10.0/docs/user_guide/server.html

I can get a server up and running and publish simple static plots, but most of the interactive examples won't run as expected. Even simple tabs won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bokeh serve` is the new tornado and websocket based Bokeh server. It is much more performant, scalable and easy to use. It was introduced in version `0.11`, which is why it is not available in a Bokeh version `0.10` install.

You were looking at the examples in the `master` branch on Github. This is always the most new, cutting edge, possibly unreleased code.  You can always find example *specific to the actual version you have installed* by navigating to:

```
https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/<RELEASE TAG>/examples
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem today.

I believe the documentation is written with the new version 0.11 already in mind.